# TIdTCPClient won't handle exception

Tags: sockets, error-handling, indy10

I migrate my old indy 9 to the indy 10 package, but i confronted to a major error :

In order, i make a new TidTCPClient :

```
TIdTCPClient* IdTCPClient = new TIdTCPClient(NULL);
```

I set Host and Port, then i connect it with :

```
IdTCPClient->Connect();
```

From now, i send data like that :

```
try
    {       
    IdTCPClient->IOHandler->WriteLn(frame);
    }
catch (const EIdException &e)
    {
    Error(e);       
    }
```

My problem is if i lost the network connection, or the server stop running, i receive an socket error 10054, wich one is handled by the catch so i disconnect my socket :

```
try
        {
        IdTCPClient->Disconnect(false);
        if(IdTCPClient->IOHandler != NULL)
            {
            IdTCPClient->IOHandler->InputBuffer->Clear();
                            }
        }
        catch(const EIdException  &ex)
        {
        }
```

But with all that, the app continue to pop an error message with the socket error, however my try catch are still here !!

So how to hide this error message sent by indy ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the debugger set to handle this exception or ignore it and let the user program handle it?  See Project/Options/Debugger Options/...

Comment: This problem happens in release mode when the application is executed within and without the IDE.